# Load default database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, config

I am using a helper function to switch to a user database in some of my model constructors like so:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('general');
    switch_to_user_db();
}
```

My general_helper does this:

```
function switch_to_user_db($userID = NULL){
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $userID = ($userID !== NULL) ? $userID : $CI->user->ID;

    $dbParams = array(
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'dbUserName',
        'password' => 'dbPassword',
        'database' => 'user_db_'.$userID,
        'dbdriver' => 'mysql'
    );

    $CI->load->database($dbParams, FALSE, TRUE);
}
```

I want to be able to switch back to the default DB when I'm finished with the user DB with another helper function, but I am not having any luck accessing the default database config items.

```
function switch_to_default_db(){
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->database('default');
    echo $CI->db->database;      //Echoes e.g. "user_db_4"
}
```

Is there any way I can access the original db config items without needing to read the actual config file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the second parameter of the load function to TRUE it will return an instance of the DB object with the setting provided.

So, instead of:

```
$CI->load->database('usrTable');
```

You can do:

```
$newDb = $CI->load->database('usrTable',TRUE);
```

Then work with the $newDb object for user database querys and the default base will be still working as usual.

By the way, you can put the config on the database.php like

```
$db['user']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['user']['username'] = 'user';
$db['user']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['user']['database'] = 'db';
```

(and the other parameters)

And then load the db like

```
$userDb = $this->load->database('user', true);
```

(or $CI if you are out of the scope)